# Load content via jQuery.load and enable backbutton and reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs, load

I have a base page that then loads content via .load() into a container div and I would like to enable the back button to traverse those load actions rather than go back to the last static page

Also when the page is reloaded it goes back to the first loaded content rather than the content the user was on.

is there a way to correct this using cookies or some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `.hash` property of `window.location` as something representing the current content.

You can then catch changes to that property (triggered by user navigation) to put the appropriate content back into the page.

There are jQuery plugins available (`jQuery.history` ?) to simplify this for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the history (called deep linking)

There are jquery plugins for something this but I prefer [SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/). I've used it a bunch of times and it has never failed me.